# how to know windows driver letter change

Tags: windows, volume, disk

I write a program to get disk SerialNumber and driver letter relationship， it works well. But user can change drive letter in disk management， I want to get the relationship realtime. Does windows has change event or notification send when driver letter change？

I have  tried WM_DEVICECHANGE event and ReadDirectoryChangesW function, but it not works.

Can somebody tell me how to know windows driver letter in a pragrom, Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [`VDS_DRIVE_LETTER_NOTIFICATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vds/ns-vds-vds_drive_letter_notification).

Answer (score 1):

After ask many peoples and searched long time. I found that no windows api notifcation or send an event to track windows drive letter. But I found windows drive letter is record in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices. We can use RegNotifyChangeKeyValue function to listen this registry value change to know windows drive letter change.